# Trying to Archive a Xamarin project in VS, getting errors

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, archive

Of course Microsoft couldn't make the error pane selectable so I have to do with a screen grab. This is my first time creating a an archive so I can publish my APK to the Google Store. This is actually more confusing than screen drivers.

It should be Step 1 do this, Step 2 do that, etc. (And yes I know the world is more complex than that).

[image: Archive Errors from VS (Xamarin)]

Comment: you should be able to see the complete build output as test in the Build window

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: VS has a build output window that should show the complete output of the build process as text.  Look at it for error messages.  The small screencap you pasted doesn't contain any helpful information.

Comment: It's not part of the build. It's from the Archive Manager. And yes, it contains very little info. I cannot save any of it (it's not even clickable). And now when I create a archive I get "AndroidApkSigner" was not given a value for the required parameter 'KeyPass'. BUT i created a key and signed it and also an alias. GRRR. It's like I'm Alice in Wonderland.

Comment: in VS Mac kicking off an archive does a build first, so I assume that VS PC does the same thing

Comment: In any case there are no build errors.

Comment: Are you able to build now

Comment: I could always build and always deploy the sign-apks to my phones.  NO errors. But when I upload to play store, I get Error from apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_MANIFEST: Missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.